# Applying package updates to Ubuntu for a Laravel app

Tags: laravel, security, package, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Laravel 7 app on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 20.4 server. Every time I ssh into the server there's a notice telling me the number of updates can be installed immediately.

As I'm not too familiar with server management, I've not updated them apart from the security updates as I'm not sure what impact they would have on the application if I were to upgrade all of them.

How do you manage package updates for a Laravel app - which ones do you update?

Also how do you enable automatic update for security patches on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Have a development environment (or any pre-production environment holding the same configuration as your production system). Update the pre-prod environment first. Let it run for a while so you can spot if something is not working well. Update the prod afterwards.